# Quarkus always giving null DataSource object

Tags: java, quarkus

I am trying to access the Datasource object but it is always giving null, I am using @Inject for that, please let me know what wrong am I doing?

```
@ApplicationScoped
@Named("a")
public class Az {

    @Inject
    Ik ik;
}

@ApplicationScoped
@Named("d")
public class Ik {

    @Inject
    AgroalDataSource ads;
}

quarkus.datasource.db-kind=postgresql
quarkus.datasource.username=root
quarkus.datasource.password=ROOT
quarkus.datasource.jdbc.driver=org.postgresql.Driver
quarkus.datasource.jdbc.url=jdbc:postgresql://url
quarkus.datasource.jdbc.max-size=20
```

It is always giving null for AgroalDataSource ads object, why it is not working, am I doing something wrong?

IT is giving below error:

> 2021-02-23 18:23:08,029 ERROR [systemLogger] (Quarkus Main Thread)
> DataSource must not be null: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
> DataSource must not be null
> at org.springframework.util.Assert.notNull(Assert.java:198)
> at org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.NamedParameterJdbcTemplate.(NamedParameterJdbcTemplate.java:90)

Answer (score -1):

Try to add

```xml
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
            <artifactId>quarkus-hibernate-orm</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

to your pom.xml

Comment: We don't  want to use hibernate.

Comment: Yes, but this adds dependencies, so you will get valid Datasource. Just do not use ORM in future, ignore.

Comment: Quarkus uses Agroal as it data source pool. Adding the specific properties to the application.properties and using the data source properly will work. 

However, recommending using a larger dependency simply because it will include the necessary dependency is overkill.

The [Quarkus site](https://quarkus.io/guides/) have very good guides to work from